# joins with where and less then condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

Here is my query:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        items.item_id,
        name,
        category,
        item_number,
        cost_price,
        unit_price,
         item_quantities.quantity
    FROM ospos_items
    LEFT JOIN item_quantities ON items.item_id = item_quantities.item_id
    WHERE
        deleted='0' OR item_quantities.quantity>='0'
";
```

my table is

```
Item table
     Name   | item_id | Cost price | Unit price | 
    shirt1  |   4     |  3800.00   | 5320.00    
    shirt2  |   5     |  3800.00   | 5320.00
    shirt3  |   6     |  3800.00   | 5320.00
    shirt5  |   7     |  2900.00   | 4060.00
```

quantities table

```
item_id | Quantity
4       |   5      
5       |   4
6       |   3
7       |   0
```

I don't want to show rows where quantity is 0.

Comment: `item_quantities.quantity> 0` perhaps.

Comment: Where does 'deleted' come from?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty why did you delete your answer? Mureinik's the same syntax you used. Or, is it because OP's question is unclear?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I realized the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `>` operator instead of `>=` and use the `and` logical operator instead of `or` in order to prevent items with `deleted = 0` and `quantity = 0` to appear:

```
SELECT    items.item_id, 
          name,
          category,
          item_number,
          cost_price,
          unit_price,
          item_quantities.quantity 
FROM      ospos_items 
LEFT JOIN item_quantities ON items.item_id = item_quantities.item_id
WHERE     deleted = 0 AND item_quantities.quantity > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below query:

```
select A.Name, A.item_id, A.Cost_price, A.Unit_price
from Item A
INNER JOIN Quantities B
ON A.item_id = B.item_id where B.Quantity > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to your tables, you should write:

`ospos_items.item_id` not items.item_id in join clause.

And i delete field delete from where statement because it isn't mentioned in your tables.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM ospos_items
LEFT JOIN item_quantities ON ospos_items.item_id = item_quantities.item_id
WHERE
    item_quantities.quantity > 0
;
```